# using UISwipeGestureRecognizers, the touchesEnded method isn't being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a game and I have swipe gestures and when I swipe the swipe method works but when I lift my finger after the swipe, the touchesEnded never gets called. But If I just touch and lift it works. Any Ideas? (I didn't really think code was needed.)

EDIT: I did figure out what is causing it... ->

> [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
>   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
>
> [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.upSwipeGestureRecognizer];
>   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.downSwipeGestureRecognizer];

Comment: This needs more code. Which `toucesEnded`? Where is the function that is supposed to be called?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following property.

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```